# References for Lie superalgebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reference-request

Does anybody know good references to learn about Lie superalgebras?  I started with Howe's "Remarks on classical invariant theory", which contains a study of osp(m,2n), and now I am reading Kac's '77 Advances paper.  I wonder if there are other helpful sources.  I am especially interested in getting a feel for the representation theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the survey by Frappat-Sciarrino-Sorba, "Dictionary on Lie Superalgebras" listed [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super+Lie+algebra)?

When you have collected more references, please feel encouraged to add them to that list there...

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware of that survey, although I guess after all this talk about nLab/mathflow I should have known to check there first before posting my question.

Comment: In fact, I started expanded that entry and added that reference only after having seen your question here. So you wouldn't have found it before.

See, I always feel that _just_ posting an answer here is a bit of a waste of energy, as it will just eventually disappear in noise. I'd much rather give the answer in a stable place such as a wiki, and then just point to that from here. That seems to be much more efficient and sustainable.

Answer (score 1):

1. D. Leites,  Lie superalgebras, J. Soviet Math. 30 (1985), 2481-2512 [http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02249121 ] - a survey.
2. M. Scheunert, The theory of Lie superalgebras. An introduction, Lect. Notes Math. 716 (1979) [should be available online].

Answer (score 1):

I like the book Varadarajan: "Supersymmetry for Mathematicians: An Introduction", but that tries to explain different aspects of supersymmetry used by physicists besides Lie superalgebras you may or may not be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick, self-learning introduction you can take a look at Alberto Elduque's talks and papers in

[Alberto Elduque’s Research](http://www.unizar.es/matematicas/algebra/elduque/)

starting first with the talk called "Simple modular Lie superalgebras; Encuentro Matemático Hispano-Marroquí (Casablanca, 2008)."

Answer (score 1):

By request, I have moved Kaplansky's never-quite-published writings on Lie and Jordan superalgebras to one of my sites, in this case

http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/superalgebra.html

I also posted some of his correspondence with Kevin McCrimmon

Comment: Link not working :(

Answer (score 1):

The representation theory has been developed by a number of people,
including Jon Brundan and Sasha Kleschchev at U. Oregon.    Take a look at
the publication list Brundan has (with PDF files) on his homepage:
http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~brundan/research.php